# AndroidStudioのテンプレートを改造したい｡(NavigationDrawerActivity)

Tags: android, android-studio

AndroidStudioのテンプレートにあるNavigationDrawerActivityのNavigationDrawerに[こちら](https://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView)のサイトを参考にして改良して見たのですが､以下のエラーがでてしまいました｡

**エラー:**

```
02-01 18:14:39.571  23825-23825/com.hoge.zousan.poyo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.hoge.zousan.piyo, PID: 23825
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hoge.zousan.piyo/com.hoge.zousan.piyo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.hoge.zousan.piyo.NavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(int, android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.hoge.zousan.piyo.NavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(int, android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout)' on a null object reference
        at com.hoge.zousan.piyo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
```

以下に`MainActivity`と`NavigationDrawerFragment`と各`Layout.xml`を示します｡

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks, PopularVideoFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, VideoSearchFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
SkillPracticeFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();


    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    //初期画面を表示
    /*
    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.FragmentContainer, VideoSearchFragment.newInstance());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    */



    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.FragmentContainer, PopularVideoFragment.newInstance());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}


@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.FragmentContainer, PopularVideoFragment.newInstance());
            break;
        case 1:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.FragmentContainer, SkillPracticeFragment.newInstance());
            break;
        case 2:
            //fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.FragmentContainer, ChannelFragment.newInstance());
            break;
        case 3:
            //fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.FragmentContainer, PlaylistFragment.newInstance());
            break;
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_popular);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_skill);

            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_channel);

            break;
        case 4:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_playlist);

            break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(String id){

}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}

}
```

**NavigationDrawerFragment.java**

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

/**
 * Remember the position of the selected item.
 */
private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

/**
 * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the user manually
 * expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
 */
private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

/**
 * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
 */
private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

/**
 * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
 */
private android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerListView;
//追加したやつ
private AnimatedExpandableListView mExListView;
private ExAdapter adapter;
private View mFragmentContainerView;

private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

private DrawerArrowDrawable drawerArrowDrawable;

public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
    // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

    drawerArrowDrawable = new DrawerArrowDrawable(getResources());
    drawerArrowDrawable.setStrokeColor(Color.WHITE);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
        mFromSavedInstanceState = true;

        drawerArrowDrawable.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
    selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    /*
    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    });
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            new String[]{
                    getString(R.string.title_popular),
                    getString(R.string.title_skill),
                    getString(R.string.title_channel),
                    getString(R.string.title_playlist)
            }));
    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    return mDrawerListView;
    */
    /*ここからオリジナル*/
    List<GroupItem> items = new ArrayList<GroupItem>();

    String[] groupNameList = {getString(R.string.title_popular), getString(R.string.title_skill),
            getString(R.string.title_channel), getString(R.string.title_playlist)};
    String[] childNameList = {getString(R.string.title_today), getString(R.string.title_last_week),
            getString(R.string.title_last_month), getString(R.string.title_latest), getString(R.string.title_skill_all)};
    String[] childHintList = {getString(R.string.hint_today), getString(R.string.hint_last_week),
            getString(R.string.hint_last_month), getString(R.string.hint_latest), getString(R.string.hint_all)};


    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        GroupItem item = new GroupItem();

        item.title = groupNameList[i];

        switch (i){
            case 0:
                for(int j=0; j<3; j++) {
                    ChildItem child = new ChildItem();
                    child.title = childNameList[j];
                    child.hint = childHintList[j];
                    item.items.add(child);
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                for(int j=3; j<5; j++){
                    ChildItem child = new ChildItem();
                    child.title = childNameList[j];
                    child.hint = childHintList[j];
                    item.items.add(child);
                }
                break;
        }
        items.add(item);
    }

    adapter = new ExAdapter(getActivity());
    adapter.setData(items);

    mExListView = (AnimatedExpandableListView)mDrawerListView.findViewById(R.id.ex_list_view);

    mExListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    mExListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            if (mExListView.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                mExListView.collapseGroupWithAnimation(groupPosition);
            } else {
                mExListView.expandGroupWithAnimation(groupPosition);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    mExListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            switch (groupPosition){
                case 0:
                    switch (childPosition){
                        case 0:
                            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                            FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                            transaction.replace(R.id.FragmentContainer, VideoSearchFragment.newInstance(0, 0));
                    }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    /*ここまでオリジナル*/

    return mDrawerListView;
}

public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
    return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
}

/**
 * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
 *
 * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
 * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
 */
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
    mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
    mDrawerToggle = new MaterialActionDrawerToggle(drawerArrowDrawable,
            getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */            /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    ) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
    // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
    if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
    if (mDrawerListView != null) {
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    }
    if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }
    if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = null;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    drawerArrowDrawable.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
    // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
    if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
        showGlobalContextActionBar();
    }
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to show the global app
 * 'context', rather than just what's in the current screen.
 */
private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
}

private ActionBar getActionBar() {
    return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
}

/**
 * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must implement.
 */
public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
    /**
     * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
     */
    void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
}

/*追加内部クラス*/
private static class GroupItem{
    String title;
    List<ChildItem> items = new ArrayList<ChildItem>();
}
private static class ChildItem{
    String title;
    String hint;
}
private static class ChildHolder{
    TextView title;
    TextView hint;
}
private static class GroupHolder{
    TextView title;
}

private class ExAdapter extends AnimatedExpandableListView.AnimatedExpandableListAdapter{
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private List<GroupItem> items;

    public ExAdapter(Context context){
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void setData(List<GroupItem> items){
        this.items=items;
    }

    @Override
    public ChildItem getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition){
        return items.get(groupPosition).items.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition){
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getRealChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                                 View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ChildHolder holder;
        ChildItem item = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if(convertView == null){
            holder = new ChildHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_item, parent, false);
            holder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
            holder.hint = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_hint);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ChildHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.title.setText(item.title);
        holder.hint.setText(item.hint);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRealChildrenCount(int groupPosition){
        return items.get(groupPosition).items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public GroupItem getGroup(int groupPosition){
        return items.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount(){
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition){
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        GroupHolder holder;
        GroupItem item = getGroup(groupPosition);
        if(convertView == null){
            holder = new GroupHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_item_group, parent, false);
            holder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (GroupHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.title.setText(item.title);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds(){
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1){
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

**fragment_navigation_drawer.xml**

```
<AnimateListView.AnimatedExpandableListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:divider="@android:color/transparent" android:dividerHeight="0dp"
android:background="#cccc" tools:context=".NavigationDrawerFragment"
android:id="@+id/ex_list_view"/>
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/FragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></FrameLayout>

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
<!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. -->
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.hoge.zousan.piyo.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer">
</FrameLayout>
```

おそらく､AndroidStudioのテンプレートのどこかに原因があるのたと考えたのですが､それがどこなのか私の力不足ゆえ発見できませんでした｡
`NavigationDrawer`を表示させて､アイテムを選択するところまでに必要なことを教えて下さい｡ よろしくお願いします｡

Comment: 暇人の戯言です。ログを拝見した結果、findFragmentById()でmNavigationDrawerFragmentの取得に失敗してnullになっているみたいですね。（多分ここは確定？）テンプレートで自動生成されるコードとの違いを拝見した結果、1. サポートライブラリとノーマルのパッケージのメソッドが混じった結果、nullになった 2. fragment_navigation_drawer.xmlの中のAnimatedExpandableListViewのonCreateあたりで実はコケてるあたりを考えましたが、掲題のソースコードでは自分には力及ばぬようです。少しでもご参考になれば……

Comment: コメントありがとうございます｡  返信が遅れてしまい申し訳ございません｡  参考にさせていただきます｡  どんな些細なことでも結構ですので､何かアドバイス等ありましたら書いていただけると幸いです｡